# SVG with holes to three.js - wrong method or bug?

Tags: svg, three.js, polygon

I want to convert a SVG to an extruded shape in three.js. The translation is done with the `transformSVGPath` function from [webgl_geometry_extrude_shapes2.html](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_extrude_shapes2).

I use this SVG path:

```
<path stroke="none" fill="#f9eebb" d="M1136.15 731.95 L1136.15 391.45 254.85 391.45 254.85 731.95 1136.15 731.95 M1418 118 L1977.6 118 1799.5 637 0 1343 0 262 126 262 126 162 1230.35 160.8 1230.05 0 1418 118 M1708.95 383.45 Q1708.95 325.35 1667.9 284.3 1626.85 243.25 1568.75 243.25 1510.65 243.25 1469.6 284.3 1428.55 325.35 1428.55 383.45 1428.55 441.55 1469.6 482.6 1510.65 523.65 1568.75 523.65 1626.85 523.65 1667.9 482.6 1708.95 441.55 1708.95 383.45" />
```

Here are the results in google-svg-editor (left) and in three.js (right) : the right beziers curves that should result in a circlular hole are not correctly converted.

[image: difference between svg and threejs]

To split the resulting shape into solid shapes and holes I'm using the `toShapes()` method.

The problem is in this code in three.js

```
// only Holes? -> probably all Shapes with wrong orientation
if ( ! newShapes[0] )   return  toShapesNoHoles( subPaths );
```

Does anyone know a working method to convert such SVG to shapes with holes? Or is it a problem in three.js?

Comment: Please show your three.js code and if possible show a live example. You can edit [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uh7xf0sL/).

Comment: I've done sample - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uh7xf0sL/8/)

Comment: Can you demonstrate your svg path is valid via a live link? updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nganddx6/). -- negative scale factors are not supported in three.js.

Comment: Some progress: http://jsfiddle.net/nganddx6/3/

Comment: Shape in this progress is correct. But main problem how automatically detect holes. 
My main goal is load svg's and make extruded objects automatically

Comment: Great question and great progress.  How far did you get with your main goal?

Comment: @VladimirRiadchenko did you manage to solve this problem? I'm trying to reach the same goal

Comment: came here after 6 years and 4 months and still problem exists.
https://discourse.threejs.org/t/svg-not-render-properly/11829/3

Answer (score 0):

the solution that I came up with is to split the `SVG` into parts without holes. and then group them together.

[image: the splitted svg]

result:
[image]